# Find text in div and goto text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, find

Hi I'm trying to achieve the following:
I'm creating a site (actually some sort of web app) that consists of panels (divs).

On one of the panels I have a substantial amount of text placed in another div:

```
    <div class="panel">

       <div id="substantialText">
          bla
          bla
          bla
          bla
       </div>

    </div>
```

I need to be able to search this text using an input field in a header and goto text location  like so (typing text in input field will call the function "findText()"...I need to find out what to write in this function:

```
    <div class="panel">

       <header>
          <div>
             <input type="text" id="searchField"  onKeyUp="findText();" /><br/>
          </div>
       </header>

       <div id="substantialText">
          bla
          bla
          bla
          bla
       </div>

    </div>
```

I have got the following but am stuck (comparing the innerhtml of the text to the value of the searchfield):

```
    function findText() 
    {
        var streng = document.getElementById(substantialText).innerHTML;
        var search =         document.getElementById(searchField).value.toString().toLowerCase();

       if(document.getElementById(felt).value.length == 0)
       {
        //don't judge me
       }
       else
       {    
        var rgxp = new RegExp(search, "gi");

        // Getting number of hits...works as intented
        alert(streng.match(rgxp).length);
       }   
    }
```

I'm thinking about using the array of hits somehow paired with their location, and then being able to cycle through the hits using the index of the array. But I cannot see how I would achieve this.

How can I get the 'substantialText' to scroll down to the hits (given an index). I have successfully been able to jump to an element containing ID or anchor but I cannot wrap my head around how to achieve the same with just a textstring.

Comment: This is too much text for the question. I've seen your code. can you give a summary what you want

Comment: Basically I need to input some text in a input field -> find and jump to occurrences, maybe be able to cycle through them (but inside a div as opposed to the entire page)

Comment: Any comments on the comment?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer ?